# Patio Tiling Proof

Tags: geometry, optimization, tiling

Call a square grid n squares wide, with a single square removed from the top left, a patio. It appears that the minimum number of squares necessary to tile a patio 2^k squares wide is 3k. This is done by adding 3 larger squares to the bottom right of the patio, each time the patio doubles in width. Can 3k be proven minimal? Here are some patios of width n = 4 through 8, in case my definition of patios was unclear.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show inductively that $3k$ is an upper bound on the minimum, and that bound is tight for $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.  But for $k=5$, the minimum is $14$:

[image]

Comment: This is WILD! Did you use a program to do an exhaustive search? Or how did you find this, if you don't mind sharing? If you have a program that can find the integer sequence for the minimal number of squares, would you mind sharing the first 20 terms or so? I would love to see them!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I replaced your text solution with an image.

Comment: @heropup Beautiful!

Comment: I used integer linear programming.  For $n\in\{1,\dots,20\}$, the minimum values are $$0,3,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12.$$

Comment: @heropup I don't mind at all.